# Pushing string literal into queue C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a circular queue data structure and am trying to pass string elements into my template array:

```
 void testCircular()
{

   // create
   cout << "Create a string Queue with the default constructor\n";
   Queue <string> q(4); // create queue with a capacity of 4

   // instructions
   cout << "\tTo add the word \"dog\", type +dog\n";
   cout << "\tTo pop the word off the queue, type -\n";
   cout << "\tTo display the state of the queue, type *\n";
   cout << "\tTo quit, type !\n";

   // interact
   char instruction;
   string word;
   try
   {
      do
      {
         cout << "\t" << q << " > ";
         cin.ignore();
         cin  >> instruction;
         switch (instruction)
         { 
            case '+':
               cin >> word;

               //here is the problem
               q.push(word);
               break;
            case '-':
               q.pop();
               break;
            case '*':
               cout << "Size:     " << q.size()                   << endl;
               cout << "Empty?    " << (q.empty() ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
               cout << "Capacity: " << q.capacity()               << endl;
               break;
            case '!':
               break;
            default:
               cout << "Invalid command\n";
         }            
      }
      while (instruction != '!');
```

My problem is when the word (i.e. dog) is pushed into my queue array, I receive a seg fault error with the following message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x59CC515F. Access violation writing location 0x5D77DCAF
```

Here is my push method:

```
template <class T>
void Queue <T>::push(const T & element)
{
    // if capacity is 0, allocate array
    if (_capacity == 0)
    {
        _capacity = 1;

        qArray = new T[_capacity];

        qArray[_back] = element;

        _numItems++;

        return;

    }
    //make sure the array is not full
    if (_numItems < _capacity)
    {

        if (_numItems != 0) // do not add onto back index for 1st insertion
        _back = (_back + 1) % _capacity;

        //push item onto queue
        qArray[_back] = element;

        _numItems++;
    }
    else
    {
        //double the array size
        realloc();
        push(element);
    }


}
```

I have read multiple posts but none of them address this problem in particular. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the `push` method of your class `Queue<T>` ?

Comment: Is `realloc()` also part of your class or is it the `std::realloc()` function ? And `push(element)` is a call to `void Queue <T>::push` right ?

Comment: realloc() is also part of my class, but it is not being called in this situation. yes the push(element) is recursively called but is also not being executed in this scenario.

Comment: Can you show me the constructor also ? And does the exception occur when adding 'dog' in a 4-capacity queue ?